# How do I consume this web service in a .NET app?

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I'm pushing the bounds of what one should ask of others with this one, but I'm totally stuck, so here goes...

This is my first web service. Not only that, it's my companies first web service - nobody I work with has ever written or consumed anything like this one. I know these things are not complicated, but for a first kick at the can, this is killing me because the API is so large.

WSDL is here: https://fast.uspspostalone.com/USPSMLXMLWeb/services/UspsMailXmlMailingServices/wsdl/UspsMailXmlMailing70.wsdl

I need to get a "FullServiceNixieDetail". Should be an XML doc. The documentation provided by USPS says I need to invoke FullServiceNixieDetailQueryRequest, and I will get back a FullServiceNixieDetailQueryResponse, which contains a FullServiceNixieDetail.

I cannot for the life of me get anything that seems to work. The code I currently have is:

```
Imports USPSACSProcessor.UPSPMailXML

Dim c As New UspsMailXmlMailingServiceClient
Dim request As New FullServiceNixieDetailQueryRequest
Dim response As FullServiceNixieDetailQueryResponse
'Assume I populate the Request object correctly here
response = c.FullServiceNixieDetailQuery(request)
```

But my response object has no FullServiceNixieDetail. Just a bunch of summary properties like TotalMessageCount etc.

How do I get my FullServiceNixieDetail XML?

Comment: Can you use something like fiddler to see and post the response xml?

Comment: I don't have access to the service yet. Just trying to get some code down while I wait for the paperwork to go through. I do have a sample XML file they provided me, but it doesn't help me write any code at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Did you populate your request with the proper authentications?

I suspect it is the response.Item that is the FullServiceNixieDetail, but without the usage knowledge of this particular web service, it's hard to confirm, you will need to find this out from the service host. You can also try doing a cast on the item to FullServiceNixieDetail, to verify this.

Comment: At this point I do not have access to the system. We are in the process of obtaining it. My managers want me to write as much of the app as possible using the WSDL. I might have to tell them I can't.

I'm hoping you are correct about the .Item. It would make sense, but it doesn't jive with their documentation. I will have access in a few days and try this out. I wanted some sort of indication that I'm at least on the right path, and I think you provided that. I will update this question with my results as soon as I can.